# Mach's principle

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, acceleration, inertial-frames, machs-principle

The question is about Mach's principle.
Suppose ther̥e is a simple pendulum comprising a bob and string suspended inside an accelerating car in space with planets,stars around it(fixed).It will stay in equilibrium making some angle with the verticle. If the car stays at the same point and rest of the universe accelerate in opposite direction then physically this situation is same as compared to the case when car accelerate but the rest of the universe does not but this time the bob will stay verticle(won't it?) So according to mach's principle how does the "bob know" what is happening in the universe and so inertial properties of it must depend on far off matter (planets,stars etc.).If we remove all the objects in the universe except the car then bob "does not know" if the car is accelerating or not and we can"t predict if it is tilted or not. But then it is the objects in the universe that define the inertial frame.Then is it correct to say that "rest of the universe accelerate but not the car"?

The car should accelerate with rest of the universe and if it is to stay at same point it should accelerate in opposite direction and bob should tilt but then again we are talking about "w.r.t point"/space is absolute.

Answer (score 1):

Mach's principle is an empirical result whose relationship to more abstract ideas is debated but appears to be physically untestable. Using distant matter to experimentally establish inertial frames yields results consistent with other methods e.g. accelerometers and Foucault pendulums.

Reasoning about counterfactual experiments is not physics. You cannot do the experiment of removing all objects from the universe, so you should not expect a realistic physical theory to capture the effect.